Literature on the design of MQW for optoelectronics
I am looking for literature that teaches how to design a MQW for optoelectronic devices, particular a phase-shifter. I see these devices being used throughout the literature and they are quite efficient. However, despite knowing the basic principle of operation, I find it overwhelming the amount of details that need to be taken into account for an optical simulation of a single quantum well. Can anyone recommend any readings?

Here is a place to start - https://www.rp-photonics.com/quantum_wells.html
